# Swift Inline Always With Debug Exception

Tags: swift, performance

I am working on a lightweight performance framework for debugging and wanted to check my understand of inline(__always) and compiler flags. If I have a function like:

```swift
@inline(__always)
func time() {
    #if DEBUG
        // do stuff
    #endif
}
```

Would compiled production code look identical to before I add a call to the `time()`? Not counting the framework code if there was any.